# return Azure AD Application Role in token requested through client_credentials grant

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am trying to return an Azure AD application role in an OAuth2 token that is requested using the client_credentials grant. No luck so far...

Based on [this article](https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad) I've created 2 applications in AD:
- MyApi, added an application role in the manifest 
- MyApiSwagger, added permissions to MyApi ReadAll and clicked "grant permissions"

The assigned permissions show up in for the MyApiSwagger app the managed application in local directory:
 [image]

When I request a token with client_credentials grant type (using Postman) a token is returned but it does not contain the application role (I parse the token using https://jwt.io/)

All documentation and articles I have found indicate that this should work... I feel there is something missing in the MyApi manifest as the "Read directory data" role from the standard Windows Active Directory app shows up in the token without any problems after I add & grant permissions...

Any idea which step I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found it with help from Alaa Husseiny from Microsoft Support.

When retrieving the token, the "resource" parameter must contain the appId from MyApi. I was using de appId from MyApiSwagger).

Roles are in the token now :)

Comment: That makes sense. I was looking through and everything you described looked good and worked well in my tests. Thanks for posting back once resolved.. else I would be still scratching my head :)

Comment: Yeah, resource identifies the API you want to call ;)

Comment: Where or how do you specify the "resource" parameter?  This is not an standard OAuth2 or OIDC piece, is it?  So far I've just found that if I include the api prefix along with the scope in my request (e.g., api://GUID/my.scope), it will work, but would be nice to not have to give an individual scope for this to work.